# How do I set up different audio sounds over different speakers simultaneously?

Tags: audio, speakers

so I have a MacBook Air 2013 running OS X El Capitan connected to an external monitor. I figured out how to play audio on both my macbook's and external monitor's speakers simultaneously. The bass and drum quality is much better on the external monitor than it is on the macbook.

Is there any way I can have the external monitor play mainly the bass and drum lines where the macbook plays the rest?

Comment: Soundflower might be able to do that, or the Midi player.